# Rewrite from C# to python

Tags: c#, python, hash, bitwise-operators

I am trying to rewrite part of code from `C#` to `Python`.
But faced some problems with `bitwise` operation.

Here is `C#` code :

```
private string _generateConfirmationHashForTime(long time, string tag)
    {
        time = 1459152870;
        byte[] decode = Convert.FromBase64String("TphBbTrbbVGJuXQ15OVZVZeBB9M=");
        int n2 = 8;
        if (tag != null)
        {
            if (tag.Length > 32)
            {
                n2 = 8 + 32;
            }
            else
            {
                n2 = 8 + tag.Length;
            }
        }
        byte[] array = new byte[n2];
        int n3 = 8;
        while (true)
        {
            int n4 = n3 - 1;
            if (n3 <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            array[n4] = (byte)time;
            time >>= 8;
            n3 = n4;
        }
        if (tag != null)
        {
            Array.Copy(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tag), 0, array, 8, n2 - 8);
        }

        try
        {
            HMACSHA1 hmacGenerator = new HMACSHA1();
            hmacGenerator.Key = decode;
            byte[] hashedData = hmacGenerator.ComputeHash(array);
            string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedData, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
            Console.WriteLine(encodedData)
            return encodedData
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null; //Fix soon: catch-all is BAD!
        }
    }
```

I rewrote it to Python:

```
 def _generateConfirmationHashForTime(self, time, tag):
    time = 1459152870
    decode = base64.b64decode("TphBbTrbbVGJuXQ15OVZVZeBB9M=")
    n2 = 8
    if tag is not None:
        if len(tag) > 32:
            n2 = 8 + 32
        else:
            n2 = 8 + len(tag)

    arrayb = [hex(time >> i & 0xff) for i in (56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0)]

    if tag is not None:
        for ch in range(0, len(tag)):
            arrayb.append(hex(ord(tag[ch])))

    arrayc = 0
    n4 = len(arrayb) - 1
    for i in range(0, len(arrayb)):
        arrayc <<= 8
        arrayc |= int(arrayb[n4], 16)
        n4 -= 1

    array_binary = binascii.a2b_hex("{:016x}".format(arrayc))
    hmacGenerator = hmac.new(decode, array_binary, hashlib.sha1)
    hashedData = hmacGenerator.digest()
    encodedData = base64.b64encode(hashedData)

    print encodedData
```

The result of hashing is not equal.

Variables **encodedData** do not match :(

Can you point where can be error in the code?

Comment: Does `arrayb` match `array`?

Comment: @elssar

debug 

from c#

`array {byte[12]} byte[]
  [0] 0 byte
  [1] 0 byte
  [2] 0 byte
  [3] 0 byte
  [4] 86 byte
  [5] 248 byte
  [6] 231 byte
  [7] 226 byte
  [8] 99 byte
  [9] 111 byte
  [10] 110 byte
  [11] 102 byte
}`

from python

`{arrayb = {list} ['0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x56', '0xf8', '0xe7', '0xe6', '0x63', '0x6f', '0x6e', '0x66']}`

They are equal but in different encoding.

Comment: @Corey yes, it is python 2.7.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I remember why I don't use Python.  Language snarks aside though...

The C# code composes an array of bytes, 8 from the `time` variable (in big-endian form, MSB first) and up to 32 from the UTF8 encoding of the `tag` string... but limited by the length of the original string, ignoring multi-byte encoding.  Not exactly ideal, but we can handle that.

The bytes from the `time` variable are simple enough:

```
arr = struct.pack(">Q", time)
```

For the `tag` string convert it to UTF8, then slice the first 32 bytes off and append it to the array:

```
arr += str(tag).encode("utf-8")[0:min(32, len(str(tag)))]
```

Up to here we're fine.  I compared the base64 encoding of `arr` against the composed message in C# and they match for my test data, as does the resultant HMAC message digest.

Here's the full code:

```
def _generateConfirmationHashForTime(time, tag):
    time = 1459152870
    decode = base64.b64decode("TphBbTrbbVGJuXQ15OVZVZeBB9M=")

    arr = struct.pack(">Q", time) 
    arr += str(tag).encode("utf-8")[0:min(32, len(str(tag)))]

    hmacGenerator = hmac.new(decode, arr, hashlib.sha1)
    hashedData = hmacGenerator.digest()
    encodedData = base64.b64encode(hashedData)

    return encodedData
```